# How to Unzip files in Python but Keep Zip Folder

Tags: python, directory, zip

I am trying to get Python to unzip all of the files in my folder, but I would like it to keep them in a newly unzipped folder with the same name as the zip folder that they came from.

For example, if my folder "Met" had two zip folders:

folder1.zip: file1

folder2.zip: file2

I would like the files to end up as follows:

Met\folder1\file1

Met\folder2\file2

Currently, the program puts both files in the Met folder:

Met\file1 and file2

```
#Unzip all zip files
zip_files = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\simon.rhee\Desktop\Met\*.zip")

i = 1
for u in zip_files:
    dir_name = os.path.splitext(u[0])
    zip_handler = zipfile.ZipFile(u,"r")
    zip_handler.extractall()
    print("Unzipping File #",i,"Complete")
```

Comment: @PM2Ring at least with python 3.4, `extractall` creates the directory if doesn't exist.

Comment: and it even works with more than 1 dir depth: `zip_handler.extractall("foo/bar/spam")` (not relevant here, but still :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, fix your `dir_name` expression as it currently doesn't work properly since it's passing the first letter of `u` to `splitext` instead of taking the radix of `u`

```
dir_name = os.path.splitext(u)[0]
```

then, pass the extra `path` argument to `extractall`

```
zipfile.ZipFile.extractall(path=dir_name)
```

if `dir_name` doesn't exist, it is created (tested with Python 3.4).